# How to synchronize between 3-4 iPad's reliably over a Wi-Fi router?

Tags: ios, ipad, networking, wifi, router

The requirement is that the synchronization should happen between 2-4 iPad's over a Wi-Fi network (router), that could go online and offline at anytime (i.e. something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNRDPDjJyfU)

I'm currently trying out this library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

But it doesn't seem to be very reliable when the distance between 2 iPads are stretched to room at a size of 150 m2. We noticed that multiple times, the packets aren't received reliably, or if received, we're getting a duplicates.

Thoughts?

Comment: 500 meters is a very long distance for a single WiFi network.  WiFi is typically good for about 50m or even less depending on the physical environment.  You will need multiple access points connected by network cables or using mesh networking to cover that range.  The network issues you are seeing over that distance is nothing to do with the software and everything to do with the WiFi network.  To cover those sorts of distances you need to engage a networking company to design an appropriate WiFi network deployment

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not very sure if it's true, because I can just utilize the router (if connected to the internet), to browser the web reliably?

Comment: Over 500 meters?  Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, must have mis-calculated. It should be about 150m2 @Paulw11

Comment: A circle of area 150m2 has a radius of about 7m, which is not very far at all. If you are talking about 150m linear distance from the router then that is also getting to be quite a way from the router.  You also need to consider the type of traffic you are sending.  Web browsing uses TCP, so it is reliable and retransmissions are automatically handled with duplicate packets rejected.  UDP is unreliable so you can have dropped packets and duplicate packets.  It is possible that TCP works perfectly when UDP doesn't if the WiFi is poor.